# Ionic 2 datetime component doesn't trigger change event when setting default value

Tags: ionic2, ionic2-datetime

I m using Ionic datetime component in my ionic app

```
    <ion-datetime 
        displayFormat="YYYY/MM/DD" 
        pickerFormat="YYYY MMMM DD" [(ngModel)]="summaryDate" 
       (ionChange)="getDashboardItemsByDate()">
   </ion-datetime>
```

and in `.ts file` I set default date to current date like this

```
 public summaryDate: any = new Date().toISOString();
```

This works perfectly fine, but however the problem I have is, it invokes `ionChange` event at the beginning (as I have set default value for this component). I just want to trigger this event when user selects the date not at the beginning when I set its default value.
Any help?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `(ngModelChange)` of angular instead of `(ionChange)`

It's a bug from ionic.
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7806
Try updating ionic to the last version, maybe it's fixed. But the angular way will work just fine.

Comment: I have updated the ionic, surprisingly issue still exist. But however angular way you mentioned works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine

```
(ionChange)="changed($event)"
```

notice ($event)